# Picking Random Names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I saw an interesting post sometime back but with no solution. Trying luck here:

There is a table which contain 10 names (U1, U2, U3..and so on). I have to choose 5 names everyday, and display one as the Editor and 4 as Contributors

While selecting the random names, I have to also consider that if one user is selected as Editor, he cannot become editor again till everyone got their chance.

The output should look similar to the following:

```
           Editor   Cont1   Cont2     Cont3    Cont4
20-Jun   U1      U8       U9         U3       U4
21-Jun    U7      U2       U5         U6       U10
22-Jun    U3      U4       U9         U2       U8
23-Jun      U4      U8       U3          U5      U2
and so on..
```

Comment: First, with the constraints given, the editor is not random.  The initial order is random, but after one cycle, it never can change.

Second, can the editor be a contributor also for the same article?

Comment: After all 10 users have had a go at Editor, the cycle probably starts afresh; the last Editor of cycle N could also be the first of cycle N+1.  And it seems clear from 'choose 5 and select 1 as editor and 4 as contributors' that the editor is not designated a contributor.

Comment: yes Jonathan you are correct..I need a SQL query for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This migth be one way to do it. Most likely, shorter versions are possible but the output seem to match your requirements.

The gist of the *solution* goes as follows

- Add a counter for every user for how many times a user has been an editor and how many times he has been a contributor.
- Select **one random user** from all users with the lowest EditorCount using a `TOP 1` and `NEWID()` and update that user's EditorCount.
- Likewise the selection(s) for contributors. Select **one random user** from all users with the lowest ContributorCount, excluding users who just been made editor/contributor and update that user's ContributeCount.

**SQL Script**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Users TABLE (
  UserName VARCHAR(3)
  , EditorCount INTEGER
  , ContributorCount INTEGER
)

DECLARE @Solutions TABLE (
  ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1, 1)
  , Editor VARCHAR(3)
  , Contributor1 VARCHAR(3)
  , Contributor2 VARCHAR(3)
  , Contributor3 VARCHAR(3)
  , Contributor4 VARCHAR(3)
)

DECLARE @Editor VARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @Contributor1 VARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @Contributor2 VARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @Contributor3 VARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @Contributor4 VARCHAR(3)

INSERT INTO @Users
SELECT 'U1', 0, 0
UNION ALL SELECT 'U2', 0, 0
UNION ALL SELECT 'U3', 0, 0
UNION ALL SELECT 'U4', 0, 0
UNION ALL SELECT 'U5', 0, 0
UNION ALL SELECT 'U6', 0, 0
UNION ALL SELECT 'U7', 0, 0
UNION ALL SELECT 'U8', 0, 0
UNION ALL SELECT 'U9', 0, 0
UNION ALL SELECT 'U0', 0, 0

/* Keep Generating combinations until at least one user has been editor for 10 times */
WHILE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Solutions WHERE ID = 30)
BEGIN
  SELECT  TOP 1 @Editor = u.UserName
  FROM    @Users u
          INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  EditorCount = MIN(EditorCount)
            FROM    @Users
          ) ec ON ec.EditorCount = u.EditorCount
  ORDER BY NEWID()
  UPDATE @Users SET EditorCount = EditorCount + 1 WHERE UserName = @Editor
  INSERT INTO @Solutions VALUES (@Editor, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)  

  SELECT  TOP 1 @Contributor1 = u.UserName
  FROM    @Users u
          INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  ContributorCount = MIN(ContributorCount)
            FROM    @Users
          ) ec ON ec.ContributorCount = u.ContributorCount
  WHERE   UserName <> @Editor
  ORDER BY NEWID()
  UPDATE @Users SET ContributorCount = ContributorCount + 1 WHERE UserName = @Contributor1
  UPDATE @Solutions SET Contributor1 = @Contributor1 WHERE Contributor1 IS NULL

  SELECT  TOP 1 @Contributor2 = u.UserName
  FROM    @Users u
          INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  ContributorCount = MIN(ContributorCount)
            FROM    @Users
          ) ec ON ec.ContributorCount = u.ContributorCount
  WHERE   UserName NOT IN (@Editor, @Contributor1)
  ORDER BY NEWID()
  UPDATE @Users SET ContributorCount = ContributorCount + 1 WHERE UserName = @Contributor2
  UPDATE @Solutions SET Contributor2 = @Contributor2 WHERE Contributor2 IS NULL

  SELECT  TOP 1 @Contributor3 = u.UserName
  FROM    @Users u
          INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  ContributorCount = MIN(ContributorCount)
            FROM    @Users
          ) ec ON ec.ContributorCount = u.ContributorCount
  WHERE   UserName NOT IN (@Editor, @Contributor1, @Contributor2)
  ORDER BY NEWID()
  UPDATE @Users SET ContributorCount = ContributorCount + 1 WHERE UserName = @Contributor3
  UPDATE @Solutions SET Contributor3 = @Contributor3 WHERE Contributor3 IS NULL

  SELECT  TOP 1 @Contributor4 = u.UserName
  FROM    @Users u
          INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  ContributorCount = MIN(ContributorCount)
            FROM    @Users
          ) ec ON ec.ContributorCount = u.ContributorCount
  WHERE   UserName NOT IN (@Editor, @Contributor1, @Contributor2, @Contributor3)
  ORDER BY NEWID()
  UPDATE @Users SET ContributorCount = ContributorCount + 1 WHERE UserName = @Contributor4
  UPDATE @Solutions SET Contributor4 = @Contributor4 WHERE Contributor4 IS NULL

END

SELECT * FROM @Solutions
SELECT * FROM @Users
```

Comment: Looks good. Great effort (+1). I bet I would not be able to convince you to use Powershell. :p

Comment: I really should get up to speed with PowerShell... one day <g>

Comment: I am not sure how to thank you..God bless you and your family! This is THE solution my entire team was banging their heads at

Comment: You can buy me a drink should you pass through Belgium

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo C# code.

Assuming you have two tables

1) **User** table which contains all the users

2) **DailyTeam** table which contains the users selected daily (your output)

```
struct Team 
{
    string name;
    int editorCount;
}
currentEditorList is a List of Team 
existingUserList is a List of Team 

currentEditorList = Get Current Editor List from DailyTeam
existingUserList = Get All Users from User and its editor count (may need left outer join)


todayTeam is a new Array

// populate the normal users to dailyTeam
while (todayTeam count is less than 4)
{
    randomIndex = generate a random number (from 0 to 9)
    userName = get name from existingUserNames[randomIndex]
    if (userName is not in todayTeam)
    {
       add userName to todayTeam
    }
}


sort existingUserList by its editorCount
editorName = get the first item from existingUserList
add editorName to todayTeam
```

Note: I would implement this algorithm in powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Here let me explain my solution or I should say logic, because I'm at a place where I **DON'T** have access to SQL Server.
So I'm not able to test it, **you may have to edit to make it work**. So explaining what my logic is..

2. First of all assuming that you will append a column (WHICH IS MUST for this logic)in your existing table say "unirow" which will have a unique number 
   assigned to each employee starting from 1.
3. Then yoy have to create a table tbl_counter with one column as number.There will be only one row (restriction) 
   and initially let it be 1.
4. As prerequisit is complete, now let's move to logic. All I did is made a self cross join for the Employees table five times
   so that you have a unique combination of team. Now all need to done is to pick unique Editors each time this query/procedure
   is executed. The output of this query/procedure will contain 5 columns 1st for editor and rest for Contributors.

BEGIN

```
DECLARE @counter number
DECLARE @limit number
DECLARE @Editor varchar(100)


select @limit=count(*) from Employees

select @counter=counter+1 from tbl_counter

IF(@counter>@limit)
begin
     set @counter=1
     update tbl_counter set counter=1
end

select @Editor=Name from Employees2 where id=@counter

select  top 1 newid() as unirow,t1.name Editor,t2.name Contributor1,
t3.name Contributor2,t4.name Contributor3,t5.name Contributor4
from Employees t1,Employees t2,Employees t3,Employees t4,Employees t5
where t1.name<>t2.name and t1.name<>t3.name and t1.name<>t4.name and t1.name<>t5.name
and t2.name<>t1.name and t2.name<>t3.name and t2.name<>t4.name and t2.name<>t5.name
and t3.name<>t2.name and t3.name<>t1.name and t3.name<>t4.name and t3.name<>t5.name
and t4.name<>t2.name and t4.name<>t3.name and t4.name<>t1.name and t4.name<>t5.name
and t5.name<>t2.name and t5.name<>t3.name and t5.name<>t4.name and t5.name<>t1.name
and t1.name=@Editor
order by unirow
```

END