# Selecting a group of names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am struggling with a query in SQL Server 2005-2008

There are 15 participants in a tournament. **Every day**, 7 random participants are chosen. Out of the 7, one is the teamleader.

The condition is that if a person has become a teamleader once, he cannot become again till *all the others (rest 14)* have got their chances.

How can i write a query to list these participants, day wise for an entire month **except sunday**

Here's the way the output expected (assuming TL is the TeamLeader and P1, P2..participants)

```
           TL     P1      P2      P3      P4      P5      P6
Jun 23 -  
Jun 24 -  
Jun 25 -  
Jun 26 -  
Jun 28 -  
Jun 29 -  
and so on...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Picking Random Names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059009/picking-random-names)

Comment: it should be possible to adjust the query you've been given in your other question. I am not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: thanks..i was not able to rewrite that for 15 users, hence posted it. Can you rewrite the query here?

Comment: it should be possible to make it work for any amount of participants but that will have to wait for another day.

Comment: oops! I need it sooner..Can anyone else help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maintain one table for the TL and create one table with All the participant and put one flag of team leader and put week No with Flag so you know that on this week that participants is team leader after all the participants flag is true then set as false to all and start again same process.
Use Rand function to select the Random participants with some calculation.